# Restrict access to page using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have installed devise and would like to restrict access to certain pages depending on whether the user has authenticated.

My first approach was to open each view, and add:

```
<% if mpuser_signed_in? %>
    #rest of code
 <%end>
```

(My model is called mpusers)

But I thought there maybe is a more elegant solution?

Dario

Answer (score 5):

Set `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the controller for the actions that require an authenticated user. In this example, we need the user to be authenticated for creation, edit and destroy actions.

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Comment: What about if I wanted the user to be authenticated to access a specific view? (Ie, I had my /tasks model, with your suggestion I would be limiting access to /tasks/new, /tasks/1/edit etc)

Comment: Then you'd add the corresponding view method to the `only:` array, it's not any different. What you're doing above would make sense if you wanted specific portions of a view to only be visible to authenticated users, but if it's the whole view, do it at the controller level.

Comment: Hi Tirdadc, thanks, just unsure about how to implement what you mean. Where can I find the method needed to display the "home" of a model? And also, is there a way to filter for specific parameters? (Ie: User ID or other custom parameters such as auth_level > 2)